# CouchDB Replication Error {"error":"not_found"}

Tags: exception, testing, couchdb, replication, suite

I have installed couchDB 1.0.1 on my linux 12.04. But as I ran the test suite, the replication section failed. The failure information is as follows:

```
Exception raised: {"error":"not_found"}
```

Another failed test include "rev_stemming". The rest of the items have passed the test. Database replication is vital to multi-master scenarios like couchDB, so could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true and only recommendation is to get upgrade your CouchDB up to the latest release ([1.6.1](http://couchdb.apache.org/#download)). CouchDB 1.0.1 recently had celebrated [4-th happy birthday](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev%40couchdb.apache.org/msg09882.html) - it's ancient, unsupported and obliviously didn't and will not receive any bugfixes. More over it's vulnerable to several [CVE issues](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cve/index.html) which were partially fixed with [1.0.4 release](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.0.html#version-1-0-4), but not at all. It's strongly recommended you to upgrade your CouchDB.